# In what form are the pieces "12 Days of Christmas" and "Green Grow the Rushes-O"?

Tags: musical-forms, choral

The two pieces in the title share similar forms. I want to know what the name for this form is, if there is one.

Basically, the form appears to be a repetition with an additional numbered fragment each time around, starting with one and going to 12.

Most people in English-speaking Western cultures know "The Twelve Days of Christmas," but if you don't know "Green Grow the Rushes-O" you can hear it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjht2xQripM&t=143s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Songs like those are called [cumulative songs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_song) (or perhaps [songs of complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Complexity_of_Songs) since computer scientist Donald Knuth published [this](https://meangreenmath.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/knuth_song_complexity.pdf) article).

I don't know of a term specifically for those based on the number twelve.
Ten Green Bottles has only ten verses. It has numbers but it counts down rather than up and nothing gets added. [The Barley Mow](https://mainlynorfolk.info/tony.rose/songs/barleymow.html) is a cumulative song but it has no numbers, and Oh Sir Jasper! actually *drops* a word each time through.